# JProfiler agent: bind communication socket to specific network interface on AIX platform

Tags: jprofiler

We try to bind the communication socket of the jprofiler agent (running in a tomcat) to a specific network interface on AIX platform cause of security reason, but we always get following error message:

`JProfiler> ERROR: Could not bind socket.`

If we delete the ip address (address=172.18.96.126) from the config everything works fine.

`CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -agentpath:/products/web/jprofiler/agent/libjprofilerti.so=address=172.18.96.126,port=8849,config=/tools/jprofiler/jprofiler_config.xml,nowait`

platform details:

- Server version: Server
- Server built: 1
- Server number: 1
- OS Name: AIX
- OS Version: 7.1
- Architecture: ppc64
- Java Home: /usr/java8_64/jre
- JVM Version: 8.0.5.41 - pap6480sr5fp41-20190919_01(SR5 FP41)
- JVM Vendor:IBM Corporation

Is there a special config needed on AIX?

Comment: Does the address parameter generally not work on your system or just with that particular IP address?

Comment: Command `ifconfig -a` shows you what IP-addresses your computer has. Command `truss -f` helps you to trace the program.

Comment: the address parameter generally works. On my local windows machine no problem but on the AIX Server, there not even 127.0.0.1 works